# Finding the essential prime implicants

Tags: boolean-expression

Given the table: [image]

I tried to find the prime implicants of the function F(w, x, y, z) = sum (0, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15). I got an essential prime implicant of xz. I was wondering if there were more essential prime implicants? I am having trouble understand how to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Prime implicant is a logical term in minimal DNF (disjunctive normal form; SOP = sum of products) or minimal CNF (conjunctive normal form; POS = product of sums) form that after removal of any of it's part it would not be a prime implicant for the output function anymore.

**Consider this easier example:**

```
 a\b  0   1  
    +---+---|
  0 | 0 | 0 |
  1 | 0 |(1)|
    +---+---+
```

You could write the output function in the DNF form as a minterm on position of literals' values: `a=1`,`b=1` ("circled" by the parenthesis in the K-map):

```
y = a*b
```

It **is** the prime implicant, **because** if you remove any of the literals (variable or the variable's negation) it wont be an implicant for the output function anymore!

Here you have only two variables, therefore you can remove from the right output function definition `y = a*b` either the a (a or its negaton) or the b (b or its negation).

Removing the b from the y = a*b you would either circle one **zero** on the position `a=1`, `b=0`:

```
 a\b  0   1  
    +---+---|
  0 | 0 | 0 |
  1 |(0   1)|
    +---+---+  wrong_output_function: y1 = a
```

or circle one *unwanted* **zero** on the position `a=0`, `b=1` by removing the a (a or its negation):

```
 a\b  0   1  
    +---+---|
  0 | 0 |(0)|
  1 | 0 |(1)|
    +---+---+  wrong_output_function: y2 = b
```

In this example by choosing to express the output function in DNF you want to circle all *ones* and NO *zero*, that is why all those two boolean expressions y1 and y2 are wrong.

**For your example**:

For finding the minimal DNF form you would like to find the largest groups (terms) possible, those have the least possible number of variables in them, without threatening the validity of the output function in this case adding a zero in any of the groups (output function's implicants).

Here you can see, that some of the groups overlap, but that is ok, because the groups have the minimal form by the definition. This K-map is minimal, because you cannot make the chosen groups any bigger.

[image: K-map]

You could for example circle the red ones not captured by the green circle separately, but in that case they would not be prime implicants, because you can make their groups bigger as seen in the previous Karnaugh map. This K-map is therefore not minimal, because there are non-prime implicants.

[image: NOT minimal K-map]

**Note: the indexes in your function does not match the indexes in my K-map, because of the different permutation of the variables. My K-maps match positions of the variables in your original K-map style. The output function is based on that.**